# Copias de variables de sesion

Tags: php

es que tengo duda sobre como se puede copiar una variable de sesion a otra. Utilize foreach pero no me funciona. Muchas gracias. Les agradeceria si me contestan pronto. Utilize foreach para realizar esta copia.

```
foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $value) 
{   
  foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart_copia"] as $key => $value)
  {
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart_copia"][$key]["id_producto"] = 
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]["id_producto"];
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart_copia"][$key]["imagen_producto"] = 
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]["imagen_producto"];
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart_copia"][$key]["nombre_producto"] = 
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]["nombre_producto"];
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart_copia"][$key]["precio_producto"] = 
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]["precio_producto"];
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart_copia"][$key]["cantidad_producto"] = 
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]["cantidad_producto"];
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart_copia"][$key]["stock_oculto"] = 
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]["stock_oculto"];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé a qué te refieres, la copia es tan sencilla como

```
$_SESSION["shopping_cart_copia"] = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"];
```

Con la simple asignación de una variable a la otra el valor de una se transfiere a la otra dando un clon de la variable

Comment: oh ok si, me complique la vida, es mas facil con este otro metodo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @LuisaPerez Marca como solución la respuesta, por favor

Answer (score 0):

Quizas esto podría funcionar:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $key => $value) 
{   
   $_SESSION["shopping_cart_copia"][$key] = $value
}
```

Este snippet itera toda la primera variable sesión copiando el arreglo entero de valores a la siguiente variable de sesión.

Comment: oh ok entiendo, muchas gracias por la ayuda.